# Sign of the electron's wave function

Tags: orbitals

What do the + and - sign of 2 lobes of the p orbital represent? I know that they are the signs of the electron's wave function but what is their significance?

Comment: They mean nothing.

Comment: There is no physical interpretation of the phase but that doesn't mean it's irrelevant